# PHP - Simple array/string manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array that contains a set of links as strings e.g.

```
[1]==> "<a href = 'this.html'> This </a>"
[2]==> "<a href = 'that.html'> That </a>"
[3]==> "<a href = 'other.html'> Other </a>"
```

What is the easiest way to echo out just the text separated by comas? e.g. so it displays:

```
This, That, Other
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll require the use of two functions, `implode` and `strip_tags`.

```
$data = array (
  "<a href='this.html'>This</a>",
  "<a href='this.html'>That</a>",
  "<a href='this.html'>Other</a>"
);

echo strip_tags (implode (", ", $data));
```

```
This, That, Other
```

---

**Links to documentation**

- **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**

  This function will glue together the elements of the array passed as second parameter with the "glue" specified as the first. `implode (":", array (1,2,3))` will result in *"1:2:3*"
- **[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**

  This function will remove the xml-elements (tags) found in the string passed as first parameter.

Comment: this explanation makes the answer outstanding, and deserve a up vote

Comment: @Jun1st thanks for the feedback, and I just made the answer a little bit better even! ;)

Comment: Thank you, my friend and genius!

Comment: @refp, there is an typo here, implode (",", array (1,2,3)) will result in "1:2:3". It will result in "1,2,3"

Comment: @Jun1st, I tested the code, it gave me `This, That, Other`, just the way asked.

Comment: @DainisAbols the typo is in the explanation of method "implode",

Answer (score 3):

```
implode(",",array_map('strip_tags',$yourarray));
```

Try this